# Meltdown/Spectre attack

Tags: side-channel

What concepts should a newbie(someone who doesn't have too much knowledge about computer architecture, user/kernel space, memory etc.) understand if he wants to know how Metldown/Spectre works?

I would say :

1. out of order execution
2. user/kernel space and how they interact
3. a little bit of how processors work

Anything else?

Comment: Yeah, that and virtual address spaces. I think Meltdown is easier to understand that Spectre, so start with that. Meltdown is a specific vulnerability, while Spectre is a class of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Doing the background research on those topics, in general and not necessarily as they relate specifically to Meltdown or Spectre, might be a good place to start as that will help him better understand. There are also great videos on the internet that use graphical representations to explain how both of those side-channel attacks work.